Dynamic Controls in MudBlazor/Blazor
I am trying to create dynamic controls in MudBlazor. I am able to do that using Dictionary, as you can see in the code below. The problem I am facing is while removing a control. When Test3 is removed, one control goes away from the display but it looks like the ref for Test4 still points to the Test3 object (please see the screenshot below). Wondering what I am doing wrong over here.
By the way, it works if the last one (Test4) is removed. The problem arises when a control on the top or somewhere in the middle is removed.
NOTE: You can run the code given below in MudBlazor playground (https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet). Once Test3 is removed, and if Test4 text is modified, the new value won't print but Test1 and Test2 will work fine.
@foreach(var value in _newValues)
 {
    
    <MudTextField T="string" Label=@value @ref=_refs[value] />
 }

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="ButtonOnClick">@ButtonText</MudButton>


<MudGrid>
    @if(_refs.Count>0){
     <MudItem xs="6">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-left mud-width-full py-8">
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="PrintValues" Class="pa-4">Print Values</MudButton>  
        </MudPaper>
    </MudItem>

    if(@_printValues){
        foreach(var value in _newValues){
                    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-left mud-width-full py-8">@_refs[value].Value</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
        }
     
    }
    
    }
    
    

</MudGrid>





@code {
    

private readonly Dictionary<string, MudTextField<string>> _refs = [];


  private List<string> _newValues = [];

  private bool _printValues = false;

  public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Remove a TextField";

  //private string _text4Value = string.Empty();


  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     _newValues = new List<string>
  {
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4"
  };;
}

void PrintValues(){
    _printValues = true;
}

void ButtonOnClick()
    {
        
      
                _newValues = new List<string>
            {
            "Test1",
                "Test2",
                "Test4"
            };

        _refs.Remove("Test3");
        ButtonText = "Removed";

         StateHasChanged();
    }


    

}

Screenshot

How are you determining Text4's ref is pointing to Text3 by the code shown?

Should be _newValues = new List
{
_refs["Test1"],
_refs["Test2"],
_refs["Test4"]
};

@jdweng I believe _refs["Test1"] would be a MudTextField object and not a string?

@mxmissile I have modified my code. If you run it MudBlazor playground link you'll see that once Test3 is removed and if you print values, the updated text for Test4 textbox won't print but Test1 and Test2  will work fine.

You have a dictionary with the key being a string which is between the square brackets.  It will return a MudTextField which is the value type of the dictionary.

The renderer is losing track of the component to DOM field mapping.  You need to add a key to each iteration like this to help it out:
@foreach (var value in _newValues)
{
    <MudTextField T="string" Label=@value @ref=_refs[value] @key="value" />
}

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkcSECFRslooYAUF


Can't thank you enough. Your solution totally fixed the issue! Just a side note: I applied this to a code which uses custom object, instead of string, as the dictionary key and the components do get preserved but the values don't.  Was just wondering if you had any idea as to why that would happen. In any case, this solves my problem so I am going to go ahead and accept this as the answer. Thanks again!

The key with @key is it needs to be unique.  Think of it as an Id.

I modified my code a little to make sure that the keys are unique but the value is still not getting retained.

`
@foreach(var value in _newValues) {
var name = value.Name;


@value.Key.FirstId   //print to check that vlaues are unique
@if (name.IndexOf("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0){
<MudDatePicker Label=@name  @ref="_refs[value.Key]" @key=value.Key.FirstId>
}
else
{
<MudTextField T="string" Label=@name  @ref="_refs[value.Key]" @key=value.Key.FirstId>
}
   </MudPaper>
 </MudItem>

}
`

Kind of strange because I get the correct values from the  controls when I modify them so the components are definitely getting preserved or in other words the @keys are working. Not sure why the values don't get preserved when the controls are removed or added.

It was a scoping issue. All set now. Thanks!

NP.  Good coding.
